# how to delay a jquery hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to delay a jquery hover event.
The code below is the code i am using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('ul.tabs li').hover(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

            $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        })

    })
```

I have tried changing it to the following code to no avail.

```
 var delay=1000, setTimeoutConst;
    $('ul.tabs li').on('hover', function() {
         setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
               var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

         }, delay);
    }, function(){
         clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );

      });
```

and here is my html code

```
  <div class="container">

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
     Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

I am still a beginner at jquery so I have no idea what to do.
some help would be helpfully helpful.
Thanks

Comment: The second part should work but you must to change the `hover` event with `mouseenter`. That's because the hover event is triggered multiple times instead of a single time for mouseenter.

Comment: you post html code also

Comment: It is based on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` already, @Matei Mihai. The mistake in the first code is that `.hover()` always needs a second function - which is missing. Also, it cannot be combined with `.on()`.

Comment: so what do i need to change the code to

Comment: Second bit of code should *almost* work. Looks like leaving out the `.on` and just writing it like this : `$('ul.tabs li').hover(function() { ...` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the reply...I tried it but it still doesn't work?

Comment: Hovering works alright, you are just referencing `$(this)` inside the timeout - making it refer to the window object and not the list item. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVoLvx?editors=001

Comment: If it's still relevant, i've found a better more elegant solution for that... see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `on('hover')` is a bad idea, instead you should use either `.hover()` or `on('mouseenter')` and `on('mouseleave')`.

The following code worked for me, note that you cannot use `this` inside the timeout function, storing the id into a variable would solve that.

I assume you want to cancel the timeout if the mouse leaves before the delay has expired, that is why I remove the timeout on `mouseleave`.

http://jsfiddle.net/k4wm1jr5/19/

```
var delay=1000, setTimeoutConst;
var tab_id, tab_id_this;

$(document).on("mouseenter", "ul.tabs li", function() {
     console.log("MOUSEENTER");
     tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
     tab_id_this = $(this).attr('id');
     setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
               //Do whatever you like here
               //your code would be approximate like this:

               $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
               $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

               $("#"+tab_id_this).addClass('current');
               $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
      }, delay);
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", "ul.tabs li", function() {
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );
});
```

---

`on('hover')` is a bad idea because of:

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a
>   shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single
>   event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine
>   event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave.
>   Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method,
>   which accepts one or two functions.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

I would use [$.hoverDelay() plugin](http://ronency.github.io/hoverDelay/) that does exactly that. It lets you configure the delay(s) for the 'in' and 'out' events like so:

```
$('ul.tabs li').hoverDelay({
  delayIn: 200,
  delayOut:700,
  handlerIn: function($element){
    $element.css({backgroundColor: 'red'});  
  },
  handlerOut: function($element){
    $element.css({backgroundColor: 'auto'});  
  }
});
```